# Show all rows from database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I've got this code in my script, and it's only showing me the first row..
Any solutions? (This is NOT my whole script)

```
    $sql = mysql_query ('select * from todo');
if (!$sql) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
$taskrow = mysql_query ('select * from todo');
        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $taak = $_POST['taak'];
    $beschrijving = $_POST['beschrijving'];
    $categorie = $_POST['categorie'];
    $prioriteit = $_POST['prioriteit'];
    $datum = $_POST['datum'];
    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO todo (taak, beschrijving, categorie, prioriteit, datum) VALUES ('$taak', '$beschrijving', '$categorie', '$prioriteit', '$datum')") or die(mysql_error());
 } ?>

<?php $task = mysql_fetch_assoc($taskrow); ?>

<td><?php echo $task['taak']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $task['beschrijving']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $task['categorie']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $task['prioriteit']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $task['datum']; ?> </td>
```

Comment: Go read a book, or go through some tutorials. For something to happen more then once, you'll need a loop somewhere. No interpeter can know magically what you want to do.

Comment: THis is pretty confusing code - you run the same SQL query twice; the first time you don't really do anything with it. Is that intentional? Secondly, interleaving your "retrieve tasks and show on web page" code with "handle the fact this might be a post" task in this way makes the code hard to read, and really hard to maintain...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By doing:

`$task = mysql_fetch_assoc($taskrow)`;

You are turning `$task` into an object, containing data from the rows selected in your DB query.

So, you need to loop through that object, in order to play with each row's data...

So try:

```
while ($task = mysql_fetch_assoc($taskrow)){?>

<td><?php echo $task['taak'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $task['beschrijving']; ?> </td>
<td><?php echo $task['categorie']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $task['prioriteit']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $task['datum']; ?> </td>  
<? } ?>
```

Comment: and it is better to use <?php while (...): ?> ... <?php endwhile; ?> when combining php + html :-)

Comment: @PietervanAlthuis Please mark this answer as correct if it worked for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php foreach($task as $key => $value) : ?>
<td><?php echo $value;?></td>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```